# Enviar data nula caso não seja preenchida

Tags: php, mysql

Como faço para inserir uma data `null` nessa função?

```
    $data_saida = $this->post('data_saida');

    //aqui pega a data se não for vazia e formata
    if($data_saida) {
        $arraydata = explode("/", $data_saida);
        $diamontado = $arraydata[2].'-'.$arraydata[1].'-'.$arraydata[0];
        $data_saida = $diamontado;
    }
```

O problema é que essa data não é obrigatória e, se o usuário não colocar nada no `form`, ele salva uma data tipo 0000-00-00.

Comment: O tipo do campo no SGBD é date e está configurado para permitir nulos?
 Problemas desse tipo estão mais relacionados com a forma que a query insere um valor nulo.

Comment: SIm, date e null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa concatenar as aspas (') com a data, para que no `else` possa enviar `null`. Segue um exemplo baseado no seu código:

```
$data_saida = $this->post('data_saida');

//aqui pega a data se não for vazia e formata
if($data_saida) {
    $arraydata = explode("/", $data_saida);
    $diamontado = $arraydata[2].'-'.$arraydata[1].'-'.$arraydata[0];
    $data_saida = "'" . $diamontado . "'";
} else {
    $data_saida = "NULL";
}

$sql = "INSERT tabela (campo_data) VALUES ($data_saida);";
```

Fazendo assim, as possíveis saídas da variável `$sql` seriam:

```
INSERT tabela (campo_data) VALUES ('2017-08-22');
```

ou

```
INSERT tabela (campo_data) VALUES (NULL);
```

Comment: Ele entrou dentro do else, porém ainda não joga o NULL, testei colocando um valor tipo 2017-02-02 e ele retornou esse valor, mas quando coloco o "NULL" ele continua retornando 0000-00-00

Comment: Mantendo o código do nosso amigo acima vou deixar um exemplo de uma tabela que salva data como null.

CREATE TABLE `seubd`.`new_table` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data_insercao` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)); o grande segredo aí está na definição no valor padrão da coluna 'DEFAULT NULL'.  abs.